# JavaScript - Calculate area of region drawn on canvas

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, time-complexity, runtime

I have a javascript function that calculates the area of a region drawn on a canvas, the function is extremely slow and makes the performance of the web app horrible, I was wondering if there is any way I can optimize it?

It works fine if a user triggers it once in a while, but there are scenarios where it will be rapidly triggered by the user, sometimes up to 200 times in 5 seconds, so it's not ideal.

```
    Tegaki.refreshMeasurements = () => {

      

      for (let layer of Tegaki.layers) {

        if (layer.name == 'background') continue;

        

        let canvas = layer.canvas

        let i, ctx, dest, data, len;

        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
        dest = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        data = dest.data,
        len = data.length;

        let totalPixels = 0;
        let totalHU = 0

        for (i = 3; i < len; i += 4) {
          if (data[i] > 0) {
            totalPixels++;
            totalHU += (Tegaki.selectedSlicePixelData[Math.floor(i/4)] + 
                       Tegaki.selectedSliceRescaleIntercept)
          }
        }

        let area = totalPixels * Tegaki.selectedSlicePixelSpacing / 100;
        let meanHU = totalHU / totalPixels
            
        let layerType = _this.layerTypes.find(t => t.id == layer.name)
        layerType.area = area;
        layerType.meanHU = meanHU

      }

    }
```

I think the part causing the most performance drop is the for-loop because the length of the image data array sometimes is over 1 million so this thing probably loops for a while.

Is there any better way to implement this?

Comment: How is the area drawn exactly? An outline drawn freehand?

Comment: the area drawn is an image that is received from the backend, the image gets drawn with ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0), then that's when I calculate the area

Comment: So the area is rectangular? Are you only counting certain pixels then?

Comment: I'm only counting the pixels that are colored, the canvas is a black rectangle, but the colored area is random, It's not a shape.

Comment: Take a look at this screenshot, I hope that makes more sense https://prnt.sc/ONSoGrzX3Wyp

Comment: Right, so you're basically counting pixels that fall inside certain color ranges? You could reduce the image to half it's size, that increases the speed to 400% but is also less accurate

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Comment: Well, the accuracy is important since it's a medical app, I'm not sure if I can down that route but I will give it a shot and see the results

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate you taking the time to help